# my SimpleAdapter does not work correctly

Tags: android, json, simpleadapter

I have a simple app,and get data in json format from server,by StringBuilder and other tools set my json in a string.my problem is that it show a strange number in each row of my listview.it show 12,6,3,3,6.my json code produce correctly and following is my codes:

myjSONcode that provided:

```
    {
  "cat": [
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "laptop",
      "amount": "12"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "book",
      "amount": "6"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "computer",
      "amount": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "game",
      "amount": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "travel",
      "amount": "6"
    }
  ],
  "success": 1
```

Class CatParser : this class get the json code and parse it to provide for set exracted information from json.

```
public class CatParser {
private static String Log_Label = "error";

private static List<HashMap<String, Object>> list_all;


public static List<HashMap<String, Object>> parseJson(String json) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cat");

        list_all = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject temp = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


            HashMap<String, Object> cats = new HashMap<>();
            cats.put("id", temp.getString("id"));
            cats.put("name ", temp.getString("name"));
            cats.put("amount", temp.getString("amount"));

            list_all.add(cats);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(Log_Label , "error in Catparser : " + e.toString());
    }


    return list_all;
}
```

Class JSONdl :this class connect to the web page of php that produce json codes and get the json code in a format of string.

```
public class JSONdl {
private static String Log_Label = "error";
public static String data = "";


public static String JsonIntoString(final String StrlUrl) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(StrlUrl);


                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }

                data = stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(Log_Label, "error in   JSONdl" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();

    return data;
}
```

and MainActivity.java : in this class i want to set a simpleAdapter on a listview,but my listview show a strange thing,it shows 12,6,3,3,6 in list view and i can't realize.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String url = "http://172.29.41.174/get_cat.php";
private static String Log_Label = "error";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setAdapter();
}


private void setAdapter() {
    try {
        String json = JSONdl.JsonIntoString(url);
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> objects = CatParser.parseJson(json);
        String[] from = {String.valueOf(R.mipmap.ic_launcher), "name", "amount"};
        int[] to = {R.id.img, R.id.name, R.id.tedad};
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), objects, R.layout.row, from, to);
        ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst);
        lst.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(Log_Label, "error in recieveJson() in Mainactivity: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are getting 12,6,3,3,6 then it is amount value picked from each object.

Comment: can you check whether these two id's R.id.img, R.id.name are shown in listview

Comment: when i get the data form amount and id key,i have no problem but when i want to get the value of name key,the app crashes.can you help me please?

Comment: can you post what type of error you are getting with the log?

Comment: @Vishwa excuse me for my delay,i change above codes and when i want to get the name value it give me following error but when i get the id or amount value it works correctly. i call this method mapList.get(1).get("name").toString():maplist is my List<Hashmap<String , object>> :java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference